# Write dataframe to CSV in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a spark dataframe to CSV file using below code

```
println("Total number of reports: " + reportDf.count())
    reportDf
    .coalesce(1)
    .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .csv("output/cluster.csv")
```

And o/p is:

```
Total number of reports: 48720
spark@monikatest:~/output/cluster.csv$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 spark spark 4096 Mar 27 20:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 spark spark 4096 Mar 27 20:56 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark    0 Mar 27 20:56 _SUCCESS
-rw-r--r-- 1 spark spark    8 Mar 27 20:56 ._SUCCESS.crc
```

No data written to file, only success file present.

Can anyone please suggest how to overcome this error.

Comment: hello @Monika did you made any progress with your issue? This relative path `output/cluster.csv` looks kind of suspicious. Could you make it absolute  `~/output/cluster.csv`?

Comment: `cluster.csv` is a directory? If spark expects a filename, it will fail when trying to open it as a file (disclaimer: I don't know spark)

Comment: Acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Comment: @alexandros-biratsis - Facing same issue with absolute path also. I am running spark in cluster mode, I think issue is because of that only. As file will be written locally in each executor node.

Comment: yes indeed it is possible so try to use hdfs path instead. Or if you don't want that at the moment try in local mode with file-system as you do right now